# ACF PACF Determination ARIMA

Tags: r, time-series, arima

Please help me confirm my understanding. For below graphs, I believe

AR(p) = 0 and MA(q) = 0

Is that correct ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, let's learn more...

As [Aashiq Reza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14910653/aashiq-reza) brought the description link, I think the `ACF` and `PACF` plots that you shared is like an `MA(2)` process.
`ARIMA(p, i,q)` has three elements, `p` is for `AR`, `i` is for difference, and `q` stands for `MA` process lag. Because the lag parameter defines the lag in the model's regression formula, if both of `p` and `q` be zero, then the model is not `ARIMA` anymore.

My suggestion: probabilistic model selection...

You can evaluate the correctness of a model for a time-series object using `information criteria` like `AIC` and `BIC`. For example, you have a preset of possible `p` and `q`, then you can test each one and get the criteria for it. The model with the least criterion is the best one. [This link](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/probabilistic-model-selection-with-aic-bic-in-python-f8471d6add32) helps with the calculation in python.

Comment: Could you explain how is this MA(2) when there are no significant lags in ACF graph ?

Comment: @HarveySpecter as far as I see, there is a significant ACF value at lag=2; That's why I guess it's MA(2). MA models have theoretical ACFs with non-zero values at the MA terms in the model and zero values elsewhere.